# ELB Keep-Alive Timeout: Varnish Configuration Assistance

Tags: amazon-web-services, varnish, tomcat8, varnish-vcl

I am looking to configure Varnish to optimize keep-alive timeout settings to work with my ELB.
The ELB is using Varnish as the backend (providing caching for Tomcat).

The keep-alive timeout value has been set within Tomcat for 120s. Testing this it works fine via that port.

```
# time telnet XXX.XX.XX.XX 8080
Trying XXX.XX.XX.XX...
Connected to XXX.XX.XX.XX
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

real    2m0.038s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.004s
```

When we try and establish a connection via the Varnish port 9000, this timeouts within 6seconds

```
[root@dev-server ~]# time telnet XXX.XX.XX.XX 9000
Trying XXX.XX.XX.XX...
Connected to XXX.XX.XX.XX.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

real    0m6.093s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Have checked several options for Varnish but nothing seems to work.

My default.vcl config for backend is as below

```
backend Example {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/service/search/test";
        .timeout = 500ms;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 8;
    }
}
```

Several forums suggests using idle_timeout or sess_timout but none of these are accepted variables.
I am running Varnish 3.0.7 and no plans of upgrade now.

As per AWS support, they recommend ELB idle timeout + 1 second for keepalive timeout and double for the request timeout in general.

For example;

```
ELB idle timeout = 60 s
Request timeout = 120 s
KeepAlive timeout = 61 s
```

We have the ELB timeout set correctly but just need to figure out how we can set this within Varnish, as the connection closes within 6 secs.
Ideally we want this to close in 120s (same value set in Tomcat)

Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The suggestions from several forums are correct, [`timeout_idle`](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishd.html#timeout-idle) (previously known as [`sess_timeout`](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishd.html) in Varnish 3) is the setting you're looking for:

> - Units: seconds
> - Default: 5
>
> Idle timeout for persistent sessions. If a HTTP request has not been received in this many seconds, the session is closed.

However, note that this is a `varnishd` parameter and not a VCL setting, so it doesn't go in your VCL but is passed as a command-line argument to `varnishd`.

To apply, add `-p sess_timeout=61` to the list of command-line arguments passed to `varnishd`. (Typically this argument would be added to your distribution's [configuration file that starts varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html), e.g., `/etc/default/varnish` on older Debian/Ubuntu).

You'll need to remember to restart the `varnishd` process (e.g., `sudo service varnish restart` on Debian/Ubuntu) for the setting to take effect.